# Spree overriding default variables.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am attempting to change sprees admin styling. I went looking through the spree_backend engine and saw that they provided a file called `_variables_override.scss` its in `app/assets/stylesheets/admin/globals/` and within the engine. I saw this inside

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------- 
Empty file to override variables in user applications.

To set your own colors, sizes or fonts just override this 
file in you're application and set variables according to
globals/_variables.scss file.
--------------------------------------------------------- */
```

So I created my own `app/assets/stylesheets/admin/globals/_variables_override.css` and copied in the data from the engines `globals/_variables.scss` thinking that spree would override the styles but it won't I tried precompiling my assets but that won't work either, this all seemed too easy. But I always thought that what you had in your app would override whatever is in an engine if it had the same the same file name in the same directory path, am I wrong to assume that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your styleshhet name needs to match exactly.  Your description lists the name as:

> app/assets/stylesheets/admin/globals/_variables_override.css

it needs to be

> app/assets/stylesheets/admin/globals/_variables_override.scss